# Understanding retry parameters of GCP cloud task queue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

GCP cloud task document doesn't explain the retry parameters in much depth. Can someone help in understanding the retry parameters specifically **MAX_INTERVAL**, **MIN_INTERVAL**, **MAX_DOUBLINGS** and **MAX_RETRY_DURATION**.

Considering that I have an http target which gets invoked whenever a task is dispatched, how to decide what should be the values of these parameters?

Comment: It's pretty clear for me in the doc. What's missing for you? https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#retry

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere so I had confusion between MIN_INTERVAL and MAX_INTERVAL . so let's say my http target is expected to complete a task in approximately x seconds. so does the value of MIN_INTERVAL be more than x ? because it might happen that even though the task is in progress, the cloud task queue might retry it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those parameters are the "retry parameters". It means, they are used ONLY when your task fails (or timeout exceeded).

When an error occurs, Cloud Task will wait a minimum of time, the `MIN_INTERVAL`. But this wait will never exceed the `MAX_INTERVAL`.

Why a `MAX_INTERVAL`? Because at each failure, you can specify the number of time that the "wait time" is doubled. It's the `MAX_DOUBLINGS` parameter.

And because you won't wait/retry eternally, the max processing duration, retries included can't exceed the `MAX_RETRY_DURATION`

Comment: Thank you. The first line made it clear.

Comment: @guillaume_blaquiere can you please clarify bit more in detail `MAX_DOUBLINGS` parameter? 
What do you mean by "wait time", do you mean time between task failure and its retry to run it again ...or something else? Also, that "wait time" is it equal to `MAX_INTERVAL` value? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is an exponential backoff before retrying the request. The MAX_DOUBLINGS parameter is doubled between each error (set it to 1, the wait time before retrying will be 1, 2, 4, 8,....). The maximum is capped by the MAX_INTERVAL parameter (set it to 10, the wait time before retrying will be 1, 2, 4, 8, 10, 10, 10,....). The sum wait time of the request can't exceed the MAX_RETRY_DURATION